# Efficient query to locate centroid of clusters in postgis?

Tags: sql, optimization, cluster-analysis, geospatial, postgis

I have a spatially-distributed collection of entities E stored and spatially indexed in a PostGis database.

Each entity has a number of indexed non-spatial attributes, such as TYPE, VALUE etc.

Is there a computationally-efficient query template for the following type of query:

```
"find the centroid of the circular region with radius X which includes the most E such that (some condition based on attribue values)"
```

eg

```
"find the centroid of the circular region with radius 1Km which contains the most E with TYPE == 'PIZZA-RESTAURANT'"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may get better answers over at sister site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take advantage of the spatial index you could use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_DWithin.html). 
What is you search space? Can the centroid be anywhere in space?

Comment: The heart of the question is really the clustering part -- what's the most efficient way to do spatial clustering based on attributes? The search space will be local geographic regions, around city-size, each containing a few thousand entities with those attributes. Each entity has geometry not geography attributes, and all are stuck to the ground -- ie altitude is not relavent here...

Comment: @Darrell Berry - That's really my question. How are you planning to divide the space? You need to have some criteria in order to do the search. Something like, every 5 meters from left to right, top to bottom (this is just an example) count how many E exist in a circular region of 1km.